# how to pass character ′ prime in wxpython?

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, character

When I am trying to insert this text `2′BR` info MySql through wx.python Textctrl, it gives me such error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128).
```

The problem is in the character `′` and I tried `encode('utf8')` still doesn't work. When I insert it into MySql manually, then I query it it show me as `2?BR`. Here is the code of insertion. Thanks.

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO TKtable (title) VALUES (%s)", (str(self.Text.GetValue())))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using the unicode version of wxPython under Python 2 (not Python 3).

The problem arises when you're calling the `str` constructor on the result of `self.Text.GetValue()`.

wxPython accept all kind of characters and return unicode strings. In your example, `Textctrl.GetValue()` return the unicode string `u"2′BR"`

`str()` try to convert it into a string, using the default encoding, which is ascii. Ascii can only represents 128 characters. The prime character "′", is not represented in ascii. That's why you have this error.

What is the encoding of your MySQL database? If you want to use strange characters like the "′" prime, you should set your database encoding to utf-8.

Then you should be able to do:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO TKtable (title) VALUES (%s)", (self.Text.GetValue(),))
```

You won't be able to successfully insert a character that doesn't exist in your database encoding.
I think the prime "′" (code 2032 in utf-8) prime doesn't even exist in latin-1.

Comment: thanks for trying to answer. I solved the problem that I can enter any character into the database by using .encode('utf8') then putting VALUES (N%s) that capital N helps the database and .encode() helps wxpython i believe. so now I have another problem, if I want to query them it appears like ??? in wxpython while it is correct in the database.

Comment: What is the encoding of the database (collation)? Are you using phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I am using wx.python. collation is utf8_general_ci